# Vue js reach child components child from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have 3 components: `Form`, `Card` and `Button`.

First, my `Button.vue` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot v-bind="{ text }">
      <button>{{ text }}</button>
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is my `Card.vue` component:

```html
<template>
  <Button text="{ text }">
    <template #default="{ text }">
      <button>{{ text }}</button>
    </template>
  </Button>
</template>

<script setup>
import Button from './Button.vue'

const props = defineProps({
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
</script>
```

And last, here is my `Form.vue` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Card text="Some text">
      <template #default="{ text }">
      </template>
    </Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Card from './Card.vue'
</script>
```

My question is, **how could I pass the text from the `Form.vue` to the `Button.vue` child component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would actually be correct. However, **if you want to pass a variable** to the component in an HTML attribute, **instead of using `text=`, you should use `:text=`**.

And instead of passing the `{ }` object, both the `Card.vue` and `Button.vue` props expect a String. So, instead of an object, pass the specific string as follows: `:text="myVariableWithStringValue"`

##### Card.vue

```html
<template>
  <Button :text="buttonText"> <!-- here need use ":text" instead of "text" -->
    <template #default="{ text }">
      <button>{{ text }}</button>
    </template>
  </Button>
</template>

<script setup>
import Button from './Button.vue'

const props = defineProps({
  // I renamed your prop from 'props.text' to 'props.buttonText' so that we don't get confused by calling everything 'text'
  buttonText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
</script>
```

##### Form.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- I renamed your prop from 'props.text' to 'props.buttonText' so that we don't get confused by calling everything 'text' --> 
    <!-- If you want give text from variable then can use :buttonText="variableName" -->
    <!-- Now, just give to "Some text" string as buttonText -->
    <Card buttonText="Some text"></Card>
    <!-- And you can't use <template> in <Card> because don't have got defined <slot> in Card.vue's template -->
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Card from './Card.vue'
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNUstqwzAQ/JVFPeRSbOixqIK2n9CrL66jtCrWA2sdCiH/ntXTNvEhvnhXmp2dGXRh784151myV8ZRajf2KEVnAPhRnWNB5Wc/HXNNXYHBEyocpQi3EEvebijC92W1hCEgBmtQGtyh+Z4RrRERmmpA+Y93bLytQnib5G0w1PphUg7BS5wdnSjt7IQQFZ4mq+HQRI7g+BAH2jQh2DP7iKt3w9jEQU1WzP1oURBH+uXTIvYhhWsBRdne+t+XtA1Mr+Vbx2LeHVuWEyBDA20s1uqKqHqZ3FZLGV7ok5WFv4zXqceCT/Aa/ZIwhb92jp5ex0n9NH/eGrLPrje6k9v9)

Seems you are overusing component and slot props, you could use just named slots:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Card>
      <template #title>Card title</template>
      Some card content
      <template #button>Some button text</template>
    </Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Card from './Card.vue'

</script>
```

Card.vue:

```
<template>
    <h2><slot name="title"></slot></h2>
    <p>
    <slot></slot>
    </p>
    <Button>
        <slot name="button"></slot>
    </Button>
</template>

<script setup>
import Button from './Button.vue'
</script>
```

Button.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <button><slot></slot></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
</script>
```